# IBM Worklight - jquery strange behavior with binding event on input

Tags: jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

I noticed a strange behavior when i try to bind `change` and `keyup` event on `input` element

```
<input type="search" id="search">

$('#search').bind("change keyup",function(){ // code });

// NOT WORKING

<input type="text" id="search">

$('#search').bind("change keyup",function(){ // code });

// WORKING
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: make a fiddle to show the problem .

Comment: Do you have both of those elements on the page at the same time? If you do, you're using invalid XHTML (even HTML5) since you have two elements with the id "search". When you're selecting #search, jQuery is going to only be able to find one of them.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra No, i don't. I tried them on their own.

Answer (score 0):

W3C specifies that

```
<input type="search">
```

is only considered by Chrome and Safari.

Plus, you may have to add the correct doctype.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Since this is for Worklight, chances are this will only ever be used on Safari and Chrome via the web views used by the underlying Cordova stack.

Comment: I used the `<input type="text">` as solution